# How To Re-verify a Domain In Google Webmaster

Tags: google-search-console, blogger

I had custom domains in Blogger few days back. Recently, I removed it because I bought my own VPS. But VPS isn't able to handle the traffic. I'm trying to switched back to Blogger.

The problem is I had deleted all my CNAME, AAAA, A records. And when I add custom domain to Blogger, it's not asking me to verify the site. Due to it, when I visit my custom domain, I see a Error 404.

How do I remove the site from Google Webmasters so that Blogger asks me to re-verify it?

EDIT: I'm not asking "How to remove a domain from Google Search results". What I'm asking is when you add a custom domain to Blogger, it asks you to add some CNAME records to your domain to verify the ownership. How to I remove the site and reverify it?

Comment: Kindly check here : http://www.edicy.com/blog/how-to-remove-your-website-or-web-page-from-google

Comment: @HelpingHands I've updated the question. Kindly see to it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The site is either verified or not in GWT. If it's not verified (perhaps it has become _unverified_, as you seem to suggest) then you should have the option to verify it? You should not have to explicitly remove the domain from GWT?

Comment: Actually Blogger and google web master both are diff.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've found the answer. I've added it. Do check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's here - https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home

This is where we can remove the sites from Google Webmasters to reverify them.